# How to do Fourier transform of an integral, whose both limit of integration and integrand depends on the variable of transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

My question is about how to Fourier transform  with respect to a variable t, the following function

$$\hat{P}(t,k)= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \displaystyle\int_{t}^{+\infty} P_0(|t_1|,k)J_0\Bigg( \frac{kh_1}{t_1}\sqrt{t_1^2 - t^2}\Bigg)  dt_1$$

where $h_1$ is a constant, $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and order zero.
   The author of the paper that i was reading(Theory of differential offset continuation; Sergey Fomel,2003), said that  the Fourier transform of $\hat{P}(t,k)$ with respect to t was a known integral, and could be expressed as

$$\hat{P}(\omega,k)= \displaystyle i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} P_0(|t_1|,k)\frac{\sin(\omega|t_1|A)}{A} \,\,\,dt_1$$

where

$$\displaystyle A=\sqrt{1 + \Bigg(\frac{kh_1}{\omega t_1}\Bigg)^2}$$

Someone could please help me to figure out, how that is done?